# Magento 1.8.1 - adding simple products to configurable product categories

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, simple-product

I need to add all my simple products associated with a configurable product to the same categories as the configurable.

I do not want to have to complete this manually nor do i want to purchase an extension.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you
Krystle

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little script. The following SQL should give you the product id of the configurable product (config_product_id, which you don't really need), its assigned category_id, and its assigned simple products (simple_product_id).

```
SELECT 
    configCategory.category_id,
    r.parent_id as config_product_id,
    r.child_id as simple_product_id
FROM catalog_product_relation as r
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as simpleEntity
    ON r.child_id = simpleEntity.entity_id
    AND simpleEntity.type_id = 'simple'
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as configEntity
    ON configEntity.entity_id = r.parent_id
    AND configEntity.type_id = 'configurable'
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as configCategory
    ON configCategory.product_id = configEntity.entity_id
```

You could then iterate over the result, and for each record, create a new record in catalog_category_product with values category_id, simple_product_id and a position value (for ordering). To prevent SQL erros because of duplicate keys, I would suggest using INSERT IGNORE statements.

Answer (score 0):

To contribute to Claudio K's answer, this updated query should to the trick, entirely:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_category_product (`category_id`,`product_id`, `position`)
SELECT 
    configCategory.category_id as category_id,
    r.child_id as product_id,
    1 as position
FROM catalog_product_relation as r
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as simpleEntity
    ON r.child_id = simpleEntity.entity_id
    AND simpleEntity.type_id = 'simple'
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as configEntity
    ON configEntity.entity_id = r.parent_id
    AND configEntity.type_id = 'configurable'
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as configCategory
    ON configCategory.product_id = configEntity.entity_id;
```

Make sure you test it on a development environment, before running it on your live shop.